# How to create dependency dripdown in octobercms

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

My models are "term" and "location". Term depends on Location. Each location has 4 term wih different start_dates and finish_dates.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: have you checked this one my be it can help you : https://octobercms.com/forum/post/dropdown-options-dependent-on-selected-value-on-other-dropdown and https://gateway.octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#field-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

In the fields definition:

```
location_id:
    label: Location
    type: dropdown

term_id:
    label: Term
    type: dropdown
    dependsOn: location
```

Then, in the controller:

```
public function getLocationOptions()
{
    // this will return an array of Location names indexed by id
    return Location::pluck('name', 'id);
}

public function getTermOptions()
{
    return Term::where('location_id', $this->location_id)->pluck('name', 'id');
}
```

For more information: [OctoberCMS Documentation](https://gateway.octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#field-dependencies)